# Mysql select query taking over 8 seconds yet limit is 5 records

Tags: php, mysql

following the answers i got on this thread [PHP MySQL Query to get most popular from two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011071/php-mysql-query-to-get-most-popular-from-two-different-tables/4536472#4536472)

ive timed the query and im getting disturbing times when calling this query. I get over 8 seconds. afrostarvideos table has about 2000 records,afrostarprofiles about 300records. even after limiting the query to only five. goto http://www.veepiz.com/index.php and check this generation time under popular artists. Please help optimize this query

```
//Get current time 
    $mtime = microtime(); 
//Split seconds and microseconds 
    $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
//Create one value for start time 
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
//Write start time into a variable 
    $tstart = $mtime;        
        $q= "SELECT `p`.*, SUM(`v`.`views`)+`p`.`views` AS `totalViews` FROM `afrostarprofiles` `p` LEFT OUTER JOIN `afrostarvideos` `v` ON `p`.`id` = `v`.`artistid`".
            "GROUP BY `p`.`id` ORDER BY SUM(`v`.`views`)+`p`.`views` DESC LIMIT $pas_start,$end";        
        $r=mysql_query($q);
//Get current time as we did at start 
    $mtime = microtime(); 
    $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
//Store end time in a variable 
    $tend = $mtime; 
//Calculate the difference 
    $totaltime = ($tend - $tstart); 
//Output result 
    printf ("Page was generated in %f seconds !", $totaltime);
```

Comment: The LIMIT is a "view" operation. It won't (necessarily) speed up a slow query -- think of it as just returning a partial result-set *after* the query has run. A good place to start is the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)'ed query plans.

Comment: It's because you are sorting the results based on a calculated column.

Comment: @Burak Guzel, im not sure what you mean. is there a way of optimizing this? or do i have to redo the whole application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing to know - as soon as you have an `ORDER BY`, the `LIMIT` doesn't help you.

Once MySQL realizes that it needs to order the results before it can limit them, it has to go through the entire table to get all the results before it orders them (and then limits them) for you.

That said (and without seeing the `EXPLAIN` for your query [which would be useful]), I'm guessing that most of the time is taken by that `LEFT JOIN`.

Make sure that there is an index on *afrostarprofiles.id* (I'm guessing it's the primary key, so you're good) and *afrostarvideos.artistid*.

Also, unless you want to get a result even when there are no matching artists in your second join, I would recommend trying a `JOIN` (otherwise known as an `INNER JOIN`) instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: how do i get an "EXPLAIN". i dnt have shell access. can i do this with phpmyadmin?

Comment: You should be able to just throw the word EXPLAIN at the beginning of your query (in phpmyadmin, or a more reasonable client) to see how the MySQL server is interpreting your query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html

Comment: PHPmyAdmin actually has an 'explain query' link built into the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous question you should cache this query, since it's a most popular thingie and *probably* doesn't need to be always up to date, all the time. I did this to one of my websites, popular stuff, it's fun to create even! A small problem, you need something like **[crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)** on your server to task a script to run this query. All in all, I **hope** you can cache this kind of stuff since it's so much better on the server.

I hope I was of help.

Comment: Would be nice to know why this was down voted. I also like to improve my knowledge.

Comment: actually Queops method cud work but its overkill. i found it was better to make another table to hold view counts every time a video is viewed or profile is viewed. $ct_members="CREATE TABLE `afrostarprofiles_stats` (".
            "`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,".
            "`sid` INT NOT NULL ,".
            "`country` TEXT NOT NULL ,".            
            "`views` INT NOT NULL );";
            mysql_query($ct_members); sid being the id in afrostarprofiles. thx for all your help. it now takes 0.003secs

Comment: Well yeh, that's also an option. Caching is very easy to implement though, I usually just save my data into an html file :P I don't think it's overkill because it can save you many many mysql queries, specially if your website is popular. Glad you solved it though.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered most of points, but I will add little bit more on "design" aspects that for any **"aggregation"** or **data-crunching operation** on large tables will always hurt performance. nothing is free :) it may not be bad idea ( rather good one ) to  pre-build them.

There are few choices for pre-building

- **Scheduled** -  Put a cron-job and choose right frequency to run it.
- **Trigger/event based** -  Most databases support triggers. So choose right event/trigger like  insert/update/delete of row in source tables, you will rebuild summary/aggregate table

Choice of option may depend on your overall application, business rules and desired results.